# This site is hard for me to read

Tags: discussion, design

I'm having a lot of issues reading this site because of the colors it's made of.  I don't know how to explain it but the way this site is set up is just hard on my eyes.  I don't have this issue with any of the other sites, and I don't like to whine and complain, but it's really making it hard for me to want to participate on this site.  Does anyone else have this issue?

/complaint

Comment: Can you identify anything about it? Is it because things are too pale?

Comment: @jcolebrand, yeah I think it might be that it's too pale.

Comment: Well keep on top of the revisions, Jin is aware and looking to make it better.

Comment: Was just going to post the same thing today when I found this duplicate.  The links, colors, highlights are all so subdued that I find myself squinting everytime I come over here from stackoverflow.  The questions/answer text is fine, it's just the other colors that cause the tendency for me to squint.

Answer (score 2):

I have darkened the link colors and question/answer body text. The change will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a plugin like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/ that lets you build apply your own CSS styles for sites.  I realize this is DBA land but even if you're not familiar I'm sure it wouldn't take you long to figure out the CSS required to change the colors to your liking.